# How to change color of SkSpriteNode from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a subclass of SkSpriteNode called GoodGuy.h /.m and i have another class called ShopScene. In `GoodGuy.m` I declare it:

```
+(id)guy{
    GoodGuy *goodGuy =[GoodGuy spriteNodeWithColor:[self choosenColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    SKSpriteNode *leftEye = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(5,5)];
    [goodGuy addChild:leftEye];
    leftEye.position = CGPointMake(-3, 8);
    SKSpriteNode *rightEye = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(5,5)];
    rightEye.position = CGPointMake(13, 8);
    [goodGuy addChild:rightEye];

    goodGuy.name= @"guy";
    goodGuy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:goodGuy.size];
    goodGuy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = guyCatergory;
    goodGuy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCatergory | groundCatergory;

    return goodGuy;
}


+(id)choosenColor{

    UIColor *color;
    long blueBought;
    long redBought;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:blueBought forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:redBought forKey:@"Red has been bought"];

    if (blueBought > 1) {
        blueBought=1;
        redBought = 0;
    }

    if (blueBought ==1) {
        redBought =0;
         color = [UIColor blueColor];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:blueBought forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
        printf("boughtBlue = %li boughtRed = %li \n",blueBought, redBought);

    }
    if (redBought == 1) {
        blueBought=0;
        printf("boughtBlue = %li boughtRed = %li \n",blueBought, redBought);

        color = [UIColor redColor];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:blueBought forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:redBought forKey:@"Red has been bought"];

    }
    return color;
}
```

I'm trying to change the color of the "GoodGuy" from shop through longs, but it isn't working. I have this in `ShopScene.m` :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location =[touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node =[self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
        boughtBlue = 1;
        boughtRed = 0;
                printf("boughtBlue = %li boughtRed = %li \n",boughtBlue, boughtRed);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:boughtBlue forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];

    SKTransition *transition =[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:1.0];
    GameScene *myScene =[[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    [self.scene.view presentScene:myScene transition:transition];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"red"]) {

        boughtBlue=0;
        boughtRed = 1;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:boughtRed forKey:@"Red has been bought"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:boughtBlue forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
        printf("boughtBlue = %li boughtRed = %li \n",boughtBlue, boughtRed);


        SKTransition *transition =[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:1.0];
        GameScene *myScene =[[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];
        [self.scene.view presentScene:myScene transition:transition];
    }
}
```

I am able to change the color to blue, but not red. Any ideas on how i can change the color?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing this line from inside the if (node name is red) touchesBegan method:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:boughtBlue forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
```

Also, Why do you have this for blue and not red?

```
if (blueBought > 1) {
    blueBought=1;
    redBought = 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

I think you are setting the NSUserDefaults values to 0 in your choosenColor. In your original code, try changing the code like this (I've added the comments for where changes were made):

```
+(id)choosenColor{

    UIColor *color;
    // Here you were setting your NSUserDefaults to 0 (you had just created the blueBought and redBought)
    // Change to to the following
    long blueBought = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
    long redBought = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Red has been bought"];
    // The rest is the same as your
    // original code
    if (blueBought > 1) {
        blueBought=1;
        redBought = 0;
    }

    if (blueBought ==1) {
        redBought =0;
        color = [UIColor blueColor];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:blueBought forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
        printf("boughtBlue = %li boughtRed = %li \n",blueBought, redBought);

    }
    if (redBought == 1) {
        blueBought=0;
        printf("boughtBlue = %li boughtRed = %li \n",blueBought, redBought);

        color = [UIColor redColor];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:blueBought forKey:@"Blue has been bought"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:redBought forKey:@"Red has been bought"];

    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: ill try deleting that line and i only have that one line for blue because when the user first downloads the app, it will be initialized as blue and so that means it red will be 0

Comment: Oh, then that's not the cause. Have a look at the answer Update.

Comment: what do you mean answer Update?

Comment: i have fixed my issue, i just set them to bools instead and made it easier. my next issue is trying to change the shape of an skspritenode without having to make another node

Comment: @AlexRabin Are you using a texture for your Sprite?

Comment: No im not, just using the regular skspritenode

Comment: Sure, but what are you declaring it as? [skspritenode spritenodewithtexture]or imagenamed? Or using a skshapenode?

Comment: @AlexRabin have you tried yourSprite.color = [UIColor whateverColor]?